# How to get the price range of bundle products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price, bundled-product

How can I get the price range of bundle products? It's complicated as the bundle product can have different settings e.g. fixed price / dynamic price?

I tried to take Magento's core code as an example, but I failed to trace it as the price range is rendered in a `_toHtml()` function.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 7):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(YOUR_ID);
$bundleObj=$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
echo $bundleObj->getMinimalPrice();// For min price
echo $bundleObj->getMaximalPrice(); // for max price
```

***Note: I am against of direct loading object with objectManager, for better impact you can inject it in your constructor***

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this answer for getting the min/max price, if you want it to display with currency formatted you need the raw number value.   The accepted answer returns an object rather than a flat value, so you need to update it to this;

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(YOUR_ID);
$bundleObj=$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
$minRaw = $bundleObj->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();// For min price
$maxRaw = $bundleObj->getMaximalPrice()->getValue(); // for max price

// Minimum price formatted
echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($minRaw,true,false);

// Maximum price formatted
echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($maxRaw,true,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bandle min/max price store in catalog_product_index_price table. You can it to product collection using method \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addPriceData and then use for output